# Subclipse installation in Flex Builder 3

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

I am getting an error in subclipse installation in flexs builder 3 professional

"No Features found on the selected site. Choose a different site or site category."

In past also, I have successfully installed sunclipse on FB3 taking help from links like 'http://markstar.co.uk/blog/2009/flashplatform/installing-and-using-subclipse-for-flex-builder-3/' and 'http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA'.

This time however I am facing some issues. I have taken following steps 
(1)Help > Software updates > Find and install > new feature install > New Archive site.
(2) Then I have browsed it to the place where I have kept the downloaded zip  'site 1.0.6'.
(3) This was reflected in the list as 'site-1.0.6'
(4) As I clicked 'Finished' an error is popping up:

"No Features found on the selected site. Choose a different site or site category."

What could be the reason for this, any idea ?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Lorenzo and Andrew for your support.
I have got the solution to this problem. Actually, the 'subclipse' was already installed for that Flex builder but I wasn't aware of. So whenever I was trying to add 'new local site'  or 'new archive site' it was displaying an error.  Actually, the message should have been that the feature is already installed but it was displaying 'No Features found on the selected site. Choose a different site or site category'.
Thanks again for your help.

Also, as I am working behind a proxy, direct upgradation using URL doesn't work for me and hence I downlaod the zip and then add it.

Answer (score 2):

Look like you are trying to use a subclipse plugin for an older version of Flex Builder. Flex Builder 3 is based on Eclipse 3.3 and you will have to use the 1.6 or the 1.4 series. Also, the "bare" zip file is usually not designed to be installed with "Software Updates".

An easy way to install Subclipse on FB 3 is:

- Help -> Software Updates -> Find and install...
- Click "Search for new features to install" then click Next
- Add the following remote sites:

  - Name: (whatever you like, I used "Subclipse")
  - URL: `http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x`
  - Name: Mylyn
  - URL: `http://archive.eclipse.org/mylyn/drops/3.2.3/v20100217-0100/e3.3`
- Check "`Mylyn`", "`Subclipse`" and "`Europa Discovery Site`" then click "Finish"
- Check the whole "`Subclipse`" tree
- From the "`Mylyn`" tree select everything except "`Java Development`" and "`Plug-in development`"
- From the "`Europa Discovery Site`" group open the "`Graphical Editor and Frameworks`" tree and select "`Graphical Editing Framework`"

If you don't need Mylyn integration don't add the remote Mylyn site and uncheck "`Subclipse Integration for Mylyn 3`" from the "`Subclipse`" subtree.

If you don't need the revision graph tool don't enable "`Europa Discovery Site`" and uncheck "`Subversion revision graph`" from the "`Subclipse`" subtree.

Comment: In my case: Help -> Software Updates -> (waiting forever...)

Answer (score 1):

The downloaded zip is designed to be extracted into the Eclipse plugins directory, not to be used with the built-in update mechanism.

In the install updates dialog, add a new remote site with name "Subclipse" and URL `http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x`.  Install everything with "(Required)" in the name.

Comment: As I am working behind a proxy, direct upgradation using URL doesn't work for me and hence I downlaod the zip and then add it.

Comment: You should be able to configure Eclipse to use your proxy, in the General->Network Connection preferences panel.